# Chrome: text rendering

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Why does text on Chrome look ragged compared to Safari or Firefox. I understand Firefox, it's a different rendering engine and has always handled fonts better, but Safari is webkit just like Chrome. Nonetheless, Chrome is rendering all fonts very poorly.

```css
a.post-tag:hover, .post-text a.post-tag:hover, .wmd-preview a.post-tag:hover {
    background-color: #3E6D8E;
    color: #E0EAF1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #37607D;
    border-right: 1px solid #37607D;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a small image showing screenshots from the browsers you're testing? (Just post an url, someone will inline the image if it looks helpful...)

Comment: or posting it to a http://jsfiddle.net/  since probably other rules are affecting this like `font-family`

Comment: OSX or Windows? And is the problem specific to a site you are developing, or does it affect all websites?

Comment: Even I am aware of this. Chrome renders fonts in a different manner and they do look rugged and a little low quality.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar problem with fonts when using external font files via @font-face, fonts look great in Firefox but look a bit distorted in Chrome and Safari, some times using different file types of fonts have helped like using .woff font file instead of the .ttf one.